# How do you create files in the downloads directory, that are visible to all users in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a file at run-time and save it in the Downloads directory. I am successfully creating the file as you can see in the screenshot below, however I can't view it.

In the code below I am checking for permissions, creating a file, writing to it and closing it. Afterwards I print the contents of the Downloads directory, so that I can confirm that the file was made. It was!

```
        Log.d("DOM", Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) + "");

        // check for permission at runtime
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        // create new file in downloads dir with name test.json
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "test.json");

        if (!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        file.setReadable(true, false);

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fileOutputStream.write("test string".getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles().length; i++)
            Log.d("DOM", Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles()[i].getAbsolutePath() + "");
```

[A screenshot of all the files in the Downloads directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMdUa.png)

The problem is that if I look at the phone's Downloads application, I don't see the created files. When I look at the folder on my computer, I also can't see the files.

Extra details:
Btw, my manifest... This is outside the application tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The following line returns false (I was printing it to the log earlier)

```
file.setReadable(true, false);
```

Also, the app only requested permission once. I think that's exactly what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Are you saying you can read and write the file just fine, but you just can't see it in the Downloads app?  What do you mean when you "look at the folder on your computer"?

Comment: I mean that I am writing to the file without errors and I can even see it when I print the contents of the Downloads folder. The problem, like you said, is that I can't see it in the Downloads app. I also tried to find the file by connecting my phone to my computer a going to the Downloads directory on my phone's "Internal Storage". When I do this, I see all the other contents of Downloads, but not my files.

Comment: The Downloads app is just showing you things that apps have downloaded, not the entire contents of a folder. I don't know about case where you attach to a computer.